# PHP Garbage Collection seems not run (Debian)

Tags: php, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Our PHP application is leaking memory somewhere, that seems to be normal with PHP, so there is the garbage collector (though we're trying to find the leaks in the long term)

I have a feeling the garbage collector isn't running at all. I know the garbage collector can't clean sessions on our Debian system, the specific cronjob for that is working. Just memory doesn't get cleaned.

Once we restart PHP on the server the memory usage drops by around 15GB, but then goes back up slowly. If the memory collection worked, it would clean that memory before, correct?

I enclosed the related php.ini settings. There are a lot of requests, the probability is not the issue.

Calling gc_collect_cycles() just returns 0.

```
session.gc_divisor  1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440
session.gc_probability  1

zend.enable_gc  On
```

Comment: If this is really the case the I suggest you report this to the PHP Developers. They are the only ones likely to be able to fix it, if in fact there is an issue

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only the PHP Devlopers could actually fox this if it was in fact an issue

Comment: Though it could be a PHP bug I rather think the error is on our end.
Is there any kind of memory that's freed by a PHP restart but not by the garbage collector?